# ea_t datatype in IDA API

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

In IDAPython, what is the `ea_t` data type? It is used in the `set_debug_name()` function as follows:

```
bool set_debug_name(ea, name)
```

If I have a 64-bits address, can it be represented by the `ea_t` data type ?

For example, in this Python script:

```
line = "ffffffff81000000 T startup_64"
addr = int(line[:16],16)
name = line[19:]
idaapi.set_debug_name(addr,name)
```

I receive this error while executing the IDA Python script:

```
TypeError: Expected an ea_t type
```

from IDA Pro:

```
Python> from idaapi import *
Python> line="ffffffff81000000 T startup_64"
Python> addr=int(line[:16],16)
Python> name=line[19:]
Python> print "addr: %x" %(addr)
addr: ffffffff81000000
Python> print name
startup_64
Python> set_debug_name(addr,name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "X\IDA Pro\IDA61\python\idaapi.py", line 23612, in set_debug_name
    return _idaapi.set_debug_name(*args)
TypeError: Expected an ea_t type
```

Are the `idaapi.py` files different for 32-bits and 64-bits IDA Pro versions?

I am using a 32-bits version of IDAPro.

Answer (score 3):

From pro.h:

```
#ifdef __EA64__
  typedef uint64 ea_t;      // effective address
```

Yes also in python it can represent a 64-bit address

32-bit and 64-bit files are the same (they're is only 1 file)

The following very basic script works fine for me on notepad.exe using 64-bit IDA;

```
Python>from idaapi import *
Python>ea = 0x0000000100003590L
Python>hex(get_byte(ea))
0x48
```

-edit-

Updated to show your script working in 32-bit IDA:

```
Python>print sys.version
2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Python>line="ffffffff81000000 T startup_64"
Python>addr=int(line[:16],16)
Python>type(addr)
<type 'long'>
Python>set_debug_name(addr,"bla")
True
Python>name=line[19:]
Python>set_debug_name(addr,name)
True
```

Did you try updating your idapython with a 'newer' version from Google code? http://code.google.com/p/idapython/

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with the Python script and the error message that I receive. addr stores a 64 bit address.

Comment: Please note that I am using 32 bit version of IDA, will it still work?

Comment: See my updated answer. For me your script also works in a 32-bit IDA instance